# Premature list sorting in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, jsx

I'm somewhat confused by the way a certain array is being sorted by a redux function. I have a list of employees which I need to sort by name.

For example I have in my default reducer state:

> employees = [Nate, John, Michael]

In the screen where this prop is rendered, I do a console.log when the component is mounted and I get:

> [Nate, John, Michael]

Now, this is where it gets strange. I have an onPress function that reorders the list alphabetically. I'm also console logging the list's value in the screen (before the action is fired), in the action (where the sorting is taking place), and in the reducer. The console.log BEFORE the action fires returns a sorted list.

```
reorderList() {
  if(this.props.employees){
      console.log("SCREEN", this.props.employees);
      this.props.reorderList(this.props.employees);
  }
}
```

Returns:

> SCREEN: [John, Michael, Nate]

It's as if the action is happening before the console.log, but I don't see how that would be possible unless I'm misunderstanding the synchronicity of RN functions.

Here's the function inside of the action which is sorting the list. I've put the same function inside of the reducer, and the action/screen logs are still returning the prematurely sorted array.

```
export const reorderList = (employees) => {
    console.log("ACTION", employees); // returns "ACTION: [John, Michael, Nate]"
    var items = employees;
    employees.sort(function(a, b){
        var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
        var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
        if (nameA < nameB) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    return {
        type: "reorder_list",
        payload: items
    }
}
```

It seems as if I'm misunderstanding something within Redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely witnessing a well-known flaw in JS (and other programming languages). Namely, the `sort` method both mutates the array behind `this` in-place and returns `this`.

The fix is to copy the array into `items` and sort it, leaving `employees` untouched:

```
const items = [...employees]
items.sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b) )
```

PS. I recommend to put the sorting code in the reducer.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. I'm still confused how even by mutating {this} it's able to do that to an event that should occur chronologically BEFORE the sorting takes places? In other words, hasn't the console.log from the screen occurred before the sorting action is invoked?

Comment: Most likely a glitch. Try to reset everything and see if the spooky thing happens on the first try. It should not. Goes to highlight how important it is to keep the action creator and reducer code pure and synchronous.